# How to add labels to intermediate images in a multi-stage docker build?

Tags: docker

I am using multi-stage docker build to build my images. I need to add some labels at runtime using the --label argument. But the labels are added only to the final image. I need to add those labels to the intermediate images as well. I can get the desire result by using LABEL command in Dockerfile. But since the labels are known during the build time, I cannot use Dockerfile to get the desired result.
Is there a way to add labels to intermediate images via --label command line?

Comment: Are you trying to add the labels after the fact i.e. after intermediate images are created using command line?

Comment: From the question its not clear if you have the labels during build time or not - can you confirm?

Comment: I know the value of the labels while running the docker build command. So intermediate images are not created yet. I do have the value of the labels during the build time. It is just that I cannot put those in Dockerfile and need to provide via command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) flag from the `docker build` command. This helps you add bits to your `Dockerfile` where `$<ARG>` can then be replaced with actual value. Example config below:

```
FROM golang:latest as builder
RUN touch text_file
RUN echo "Argument value: ${MAIN_ARG}" > text_file

FROM alpine:latest

COPY --from=0 /go/text_file /text_file
```

Then you can pass the `MAIN` value as follows:

```
$> docker build -t alpine_arg:latest --build-arg MAIN_ARG="Hello" .
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on what is happening here? Are you just passing a variable through? where us the labling happening?